# Monitoring packets dropped by kernel

Tags: networking

We had an network (dropped packets by kernel) issue with a Red Hat Server RHEL 5.2 which has been solved.

However , we want to prevent this kind of problems so i'd like to know is if there's any way to monitor number of packets dropped by kernel without having to enter in debugging mode?

Thanks

Marck

Answer (score 2):

If you want more details about why your packets are dropped you can also use Dropwatch. Dropwatch is a command line tool allowing you to see where the packet were dropped in the kernel. It can be useful when seeking to understand **why** your packets were dropped :

https://linux.die.net/man/1/dropwatch

Answer (score 1):

Usually, dropped packects appear on a counter when you type ifconfig.

```
          RX packets:164839152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6080484254 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
```

Depending on your monitoring system, you should be able to write a script that parses the output of ifconfig and displays an alert if the number of errors of dropped packets is too high.